# Implementing tree structure on c#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have an object myBook.

Can I implement a better structure for that kind of data?

```
public class myRow{

    public int ID = 0;
    public int number = 0;
    public String param1 = null;
    public decimal param2 = null;
    public string parm3 = "";
    public int param4 = null;

}

public class mySubChapter{

   public int ID = 0;
   public string title = "";   
   public List<myRow> rows;

   internal bool sort(){...}  //sort rows by ID
}

public class myChapter{

   public int ID = 0;
   public string title = "";
   public List<mySubChapter> subChapters;

   internal bool sort(){...}  //sort subChapters by ID
}

public class myBook{
    public int ID = 0;
    public string title = ""
    public List<myChapter> chapters;

     internal bool sort(){...}  //sort chapters by ID
}
```

Comment: For what purpose is this data structure? Do you want to Keep the whole book's text in it or just the information like in a library catalogue?

Comment: @PMF i will save all data in the object, i will need to serialize it and transfer it to another client.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to model your book structure in a tree, you could use a generic tree implementation like the one presented [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12592/Generic-Tree-T-in-C). Then, you could form a tree using code like this

```
DTreeNode<string> root = new DTreeNode<string>();
DTreeNode<string> temp;

temp = root.Nodes.Add("Hello");
temp.Nodes.Add("olleH");

temp = root.Nodes.Add("World");
temp.Nodes.AddRange(new string[] 
        { "dWorl", "ldWor", "rldWo", "orldW" } );
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I'll merge subchapter and chapper class into one myChaper class and add new property is chapterLevel in it. Because I think subChapter is a chapter too with just difference level(children of chapter may be). Sorry for my English.

```
public class myRow{

    public int ID = 0;
    public int number = 0;
    public String param1 = null;
    public decimal param2 = null;
    public string parm3 = "";
    public int param4 = null;

}

public class myChapter{

   public int ID = 0;
   public string title = "";
   public int chapterLevel = 0;

   internal bool sort(){...}  //sort chapters by ID and level
}

public class myBook{
    public int ID = 0;
    public string title = ""
    public List<myChapter> chapters;

     internal bool sort(){...}  //sort chapters by ID
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another tree implementation:

```
public interface INode
{
    int Id { get; set; }

    INode Parent { get; }

    ReadOnlyCollection<INode> Children { get; }

    void SetParent(INode node);

    void AddChild(INode node);
}

public class Node : INode
{
    private INode _parent;

    private IList<INode> _children;

    public Node()
    {
        _children = new List<INode>();    
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public INode Parent
    {
        get { return _parent; }
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<INode> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return new ReadOnlyCollection<INode>
                       (_children.OrderBy(c => c.Id).ToList());
        }
    }

    public virtual void AddNode(INode node)
    {
        _children.Add(node);

        node.SetParent(this);
    }

    public virtual void SetParent(INode node)
    {
        _parent = node;
    }
}
```

The classes, Row, Chapter, Book can derive from the Node class, e.g.

```
public class Book : Node
{
    public override void SetParent(INode node)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```